# Codeigniter 3 'Too few arguments to function 0 exactly 1 expected'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie in programming and get a problem with my script. I hope you can help me.

This is my problem :

> An uncaught exception was encountered
>
> Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function M_warisantb::Caridata(), 0
> passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\budaya\dapobud\application\controllers\Home.php on
> line 58 and exactly 1 expected
>
> Filename:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\budaya\dapobud\application\models\M_warisantb.php
>
> Line Number: 12
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\budaya\dapobud\application\controllers\Home.php
> Line: 58 Function: Caridata
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\budaya\dapobud\index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once

I'm trying to make a search with select query (in Codeigniter 3)
I start to build a form to start the search like this :

```html
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('Home/Cari');?>" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input name="cari" type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="cari" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
             <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
          </button>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

and I create model to run this function like this :

```
public function Caridata($cari)
{
    $this->db->like('domain_opk', $cari);
    return $this->db->get_where('tradisi')->result_array();
}
```

in my opinion `$cari` come from `<input name="cari" type="text">`

This is my controller

```
public function Cari()
{
    $data['title'] ='Galeri Foto';  
    $data['tradisi'] = $this->M_warisantb->Caridata();
    $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('templates/topbargaleri');
    $this->load->view('templates/galeri',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In model you have created a function **Caridata** which is parameterized and as you mentioned that parameter is from your form so, first fetch the input value from form and then pass it to the function when you are calling it in controller. Simply as below -

```
$name = $this->input->post('cari');
```

Then, instead of -

```
$data['tradisi'] = $this->M_warisantb->Caridata();
```

Do this -

```
$data['tradisi'] = $this->M_warisantb->Caridata($name);
```